# Why the Fubini theorem fail??

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f(x,y)=\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ prove:

$$\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1f(x,y)dy\right)dx=\frac{\pi}{4}\tag1$$

$$\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1f(x,y)dx\right)dy=\frac{-\pi}{4}\tag2$$

> Why the Fubini theorem fail??

**My attempt:**

For $(1)$ we have:

$$\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1f(x,y)dy\right)dx=\int\int\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\right)=\int \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\bigg|_{y = 0}^{y = 1}dx=\int\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx= \\ =\arctan(x)\bigg|_0^1=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

For $(2)$ we have:

$$\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1f(x,y)dx\right)dy=\int\int\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{-x}{x^2+y^2}\right)dxdy=-\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+y^2}dy=-\frac{\pi}{4}$$

I don't have very clear why Fubini Theorem fail. Can someone help me?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem (Fubini-Tonelli Theorem)

Comment: You should read the Fubini theorem carefully, looking at the assumptions.  One of them will not be satisfied by your problem.

Comment: I think simply because it is not absolutely integrable?

Comment: The function $f(x,y)$ is continuous on the unit square without the origin (0,0) but it is *not* bounded on the unit square because of issues near the point $(0,0)$. For example, $f(x,tx) = ((1-t^2)/(1+t^2)^2)(1/x^2)$ for $0 < x \leq 1$ and $0 < t \leq 1$. The positive function $1/x^2$ is not integrable on $(0,1]$ because of problems near $x = 0$.

Comment: Fubini's theorem does not fail.

Comment: Hi! Regarding the second equality of the first equation, why the discontinuity of f(x,y) at 0 does not matter when applying what I think is some version of the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By symmetry (via Tonelli's theorem),
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 |f(x,y)|\,dy\,dx &= 2\int_0^1\int_0^x \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dy\,dx \\&= 2\int_0^1\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}|_{y=0}^{y=x}\,dx \\ &= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\,dx \\&= \infty
\end{align*}$$
Therefore, since $f(x,y)$ is not integrable over $[0,1]^2,$ Fubini's theorem doesn't apply.

Comment: To be clear, we can use Tonelli's theorem to evaluate the double integral as either of the integrated integrals because $(x,y)\mapsto |f(x,y)|$ is nonnegative, correct?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes.  That isn't the use of Tonelli's theorem I referenced at the beginning (which is about changing the order of an iterated integral), but Tonelli's theorem is what allows us to use a multiple integral or iterated integrals when investigating whether a function is integrable.

Comment: Why does the first equality hold? Where does the factor of 2 come from?

Comment: @NoppaweeApichonpongpan Write the first integral as $$\int_0^1\int_0^1 |f(x,y)|\,dy\,dx = \int_0^1\int_0^x |f(x,y)|\,dy\,dx + \int_0^1\int_0^y |f(x,y)|\,dx\,dy$$ (note the use of Tonelli's theorem).  Then use symmetry of $f$.